# Know which condition didn't match in mysql consult

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, return-value

Into a very high selective MySQL query, is there a way to know which condition did not match?
Eg.: If I'm looking for 12 conditions and my MySQL returns 0, wich one of these 12 conditions did not match?

```
SELECT
    article.id,
    article.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name order by tags.name) AS nameTags,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.id order by tags.id) AS idTags,
    MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var1%',1,0)) AS var1match,
    MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var2%',1,0)) AS var2match,
    and more 10 conditions.
FROM
    article
    LEFT JOIN ....
    LEFT JOIN ....
GROUP BY id
HAVING
    (nameTags LIKE '%var1%' OR var1match=1)
    AND (nameTags LIKE '%var2%' OR var2match=1)
    AND more 10 conditions.
```

I mean, do it without make 12 single consults to see which one results nothing.

---

**Update**: Got some evolution

If I do this:

```
SELECT
    article.id,
        MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var1%',1,0) AS var1,
        MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var2%',1,0) AS var2,
        MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var3%',1,0) AS var3,
FROM
    article
    LEFT JOIN ....
    LEFT JOIN ....
GROUP BY article.id
```

I'll get an aliased table like this

```
|id|var1|var2|var3|
| 1|   0|   0|   1|
| 2|   0|   1|   0|
| 3|   0|   0|   0|
| 4|   0|   1|   1|
```

So I know that 'var 1' doesn't match with the condition because all column value is equal 0. How I get the return of that column name?

Tried to sum value and get columns that `sum = 0`. Don't know how to do.

---

**Update:**
Found to do that is using temporary tables.

1) Create tmp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tagReport AS
SELECT
    article.id,
        MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var1%',1,0) AS l_var1,
        MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var2%',1,0) AS l_var2,
        MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var3%',1,0) AS l_var3,
FROM
    article
    LEFT JOIN ....
    LEFT JOIN ....
GROUP BY article.id
```

You'll have something like this:

```
|id|l_var1|l_var2|l_var3|
| 1|     0|     0|     1|
| 2|     0|     1|     0|
| 3|     0|     0|     0|
| 4|     0|     1|     1|
```

2) Sum values and you will know that column with 0 has no match

```
SELECT
 SUM(l_var1) as l_var1,
 SUM(l_var2) as l_var2,
 SUM(l_var3) as l_var3
```

You'll get something like this:

```
|l_var1|l_var2|l_var3|
|     0|     2|     2|
```

3) Get name of columns with `value = 0` in PHP

```
$querySelect = "SELECT
 SUM(l_var1) as l_var1,
 SUM(l_var2) as l_var2,
 SUM(l_var3) as l_var3
";
$result = mysql_query($querySelect);
$arrayUnfound = array_keys(@mysql_fetch_assoc($result), "0");
print_r($arrayUnfound)
```

4) It is a temporary table, but I added a drop table just to make sure and try to free memory:

```
mysql_query("DROP TABLE tmp_tagReport; ");
```

I found myself a way to do it, but it **still has to make 2 or more queries**. However I hope it could be helpful.

*sorry my english*

Thanks

Comment: Your use of `HAVING nameTags LIKE '%var1%'` is a poor choice, because it's operating over a `GROUP_CONCAT`, which will give poor performance. Better to use `WHERE` on the column directly.

Comment: I don't know how to use WHERE in Aliased Column. If I condition it by WHERE, I have to use like `'WHERE tags.name' LIKE '%var1%'` and it brokes my query result. It only seems to work in tags.name instead nameTags. In this case I need to do a second query to receive all result I want (all vales concatenated). Is it better do 2 queries than use HAVING? I'm accepting suggestions, hints and tips!